# Github php page not found

Tags: php, html, github

When I upload HTML file (like `index.html`) web page works good, but when I upload `index.php` and then refresh it shows 404 error:

> There isn't a GitHub Page here.

Comment: GitHub pages does not support server-side code.

Comment: This question is extremely vague

Comment: Are you uploading PHP to GitHub? They don't run PHP on their servers, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read more about:
https://pages.github.com/
and jekyll can do the job that you want too
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/

here well coded site "app" hosted in github:

https://github.com/thedereck/gh-pages-blog